# Using the animation package

Tags: r, rstudio

I am new to R and trying to use the animation package. From the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/animation.pdf), I tried to run this snippet

```
library(animation)
oopt = ani.options(interval = 0.2, nmax = 10)
## use a loop to create images one by one
for (i in 1:ani.options("nmax")) {
  plot(rnorm(30))
  ani.pause() ## pause for a while (’interval’)
}
## restore the options
ani.options(oopt)
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in ani.options(oopt) : object 'oopt' not found
```

I am have the package installed and I am using ver 2.14.2

Comment: Eh, maybe a stupid question, but did you load the package using `library(animation)`?

Comment: @ROLO (edited the question) yes. now I did. So it wasn't a stupid question.

Comment: Well, this code works for me. You might want to change `oopt = ` in `oopt <-`, as `<-` is the normal assignment operator, but this does not change anything in this case.

Comment: @ROLO I made the changes, but it still is not running. n00b question, am I doing this right? In Rstudio I save the macro, ani.r and press run?

Comment: It's not going to make a difference using = rather than the arrow for assignment

Comment: Do you do 'run all' (Ctrl-Shift-R)?

Comment: @ROLO that was precisely the problem. I didn't know that how the function is evaluated depends on the cursor position in R studio. When I took the cursor to the top, and ran it again, it worked. Earlier it began evaluating from the beginning of the last line. Could you post your above comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RStudio can evaluate your code line by line: Ctrl-Enter runs the line at the cursor in the source. You can see in the Console below your source that in this case only one line will have been evaluated.
To run your full script, use 'run all' (Ctrl-Shift-R).

Instead of running from the source code window, you can also type in a line of code directly and evaluate it by pressing Enter.